# Como trocar a cor de fundo e a cor do icone em uma imagem

Tags: xamarin-forms

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno App usando Xamarin Forms Cross Platform (Android e iOS). Preciso controlar a cor de fundo e do icone das imagens, conforme mostrado no exemplo abaixo.

Tentei alguns plugins para Xamarin Forms sem sucesso, pois só consigo alterar a cor de fundo da imagem.

Alguem tem alguma dica?

Exemplo (apenas dar ideia da necessidade):

**Imagem Original**

[image: Imagem Original]

**Imagem Desejada**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparentemente isso parece encaixar no efeito de filtro. No caso do exemplo, seria aplicar um azul semi transparente sobre a imagem. Acho até que dá para fazer algo nesse sentido no forma, mas o ideal seria usar recursos da plataforma específica.

Comment: Acho que dá para fazer sim. Por favor edite sua questão esclarecem um pouco o problema para que a gente possa solicitar a reavaliação e talvez reabertura da penha. Acho que dá para fazer o que você precisa sim

Comment: Corretor maldito. Acho que você entendeu o que eu quis dizer, neh?